# React with Firebase Auth: How to set Persistence?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm running into an error with my Login:

```
const Login = ({ history }) => {
const handleLogin = useCallback(
    async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { email, password } = event.target.elements;
        try {
            await app
                .auth()
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
            app.auth().setPersistence(app.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);
            history.push("/feed");
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    },
    [history]
);
```

I think that my setPersistence is at the wrong place but I don't know how to fix that. 
My import list:

```
import React, { useCallback, useContext } from "react";
import { withRouter, Redirect } from "react-router";
import app from "../../firebase";
import { AuthContext } from "../../Auth";
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call setPersistence before calling signInWithEmailAndPassword.

```
const Login = ({ history }) => {
const handleLogin = useCallback(
    async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { email, password } = event.target.elements;
        try {
            await app.auth().setPersistence(app.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);
            await app
                .auth()
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
            history.push("/feed");
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    },
    [history]
);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer!
I've tried that but receive an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Persistence' of undefined" 
If you have an idea let me know! Thank you!

Comment: I've got it working. 
Just need to import * as firebase from "firebase/auth" and then use firebase instead of app at "firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION".
Thank you a lot for your help!