# How can I prevent a login every time I go to a page using firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication. I am running into some problems using it. I am using react to build my project.

I want a page to be shown only if a user is logged in. I partially achieve this, but if I go to another page then return, it asks me to login again. If I refresh the page, it asks me to login again. It's not remembering my login status.

I tried using onAuthStateChange, but I dont think its working how I want, I just want to check if the current user is logged in (when i first go to the page, or even if i do a refresh, check if user is logged in). I also tried auth.currentUser, it also failed. maybe I am doing it wrong

!(Should I use a cookie to store the user object? is that the right way or secure way to do it? what if the user blocks all cookies?)

here is my code

```js
import Head from "next/head";
import { auth } from "../../components/firebase";
import Login from "../Login";
import AddProperty from "../../components/AddProperty";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const Properties = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setUser(user);
      console.log(user);
    });
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Add Property</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="web dev" />
      </Head>
      <h1>Add Property</h1>
      <p>Welcome to the add Property new</p>
      {console.log("user logged in? " + user)}
      {user ? (
        <AddProperty />
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p style={{ color: "red" }}>You must be loggedin to add a property</p>{" "}
          <Login />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Properties;
```

Comment: `localStorage` :)

Comment: and the user cannot block that access right ? or is there a way to check the current status to the auth server, if the token is legit, show the page ?

Comment: found a solution here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKwu15ldZ7k&t=1097s&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified

Answer (score 0):

See the firebase [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence),
The variable firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence supports three values:

> '**local**': Indicates that the state will be persisted even when the
> browser window is closed or the activity is destroyed in React Native.
>
> '**session**': Indicates that the state will only persist in the
> current session or tab, and will be cleared when the tab or window in
> which the user authenticated is closed.
>
> '**none**': Indicates that the state will only be stored in memory and
> will be cleared when the window or activity is refreshed.

Or you can check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59148227/8973254)

Comment: I did set persistence on my login page, my problem is that i am on another page that requires login, Even when i login its asking me to login again if i refresh the page.